# How to handle internal data

Tags: c, c89

I want to write a limitation system.

- The user can use `extendCmd()` or `retractCmd()` to extend or retract an object.
- He can set a max extension by extending the object to a certain point and call `setMaxExtension()`. When the value is set, the object may not be extended when it is longer than the set value
- He can `clearMaxExtension()`.
- `calculateExt()` uses multiple sensors to get the value

To do this I have to save the extension internally (it is not necessary to give numeric values to the user).

I came up with the following design(rough outline, returns and needed arguments are removed for clarity):

```
static int maxExt;
static bool MaxIsSet;

static void extend(){...};
static void retract(){...};
static void calculateExt(){...};

void extendCmd()
{
  const int currentExt = calculateExt();
  if( !maxIsSet || !(maxExt < currentExt))
  {
    extend();
  }
}

void retractCmd()
{
  const int currentExt = calculateExt();
  if( currentExt > 0 )
  {
    retract();
  }
}

void setMaxExtension()
{
  maxExt = calculateExt();
  maxIsSet = true;
}

void clearMaxExtension()
{
  maxExt = 0;
  maxIsSet = false;
}
```

This way I expose the the needed functions to the main program and have something like get and set for my internal variables.

In current practice is it okay to have variables in translation unit scope and use them directly? Or should I pass them as arguments to the functions?

I could also wrap everything in one function and do the signal handling myself, but I would prefer something like above.

Comment: A key question is probably how many objects are involved? The pseudo code above essentially assumes there's only one. If there is (or can be) more than one, then is the number of objects: **(a)** fixed at compile time? **(b)** fixed once at run-time? or **(c)** objects can be created/removed at will? The answers will shape the best way of doing this.

Comment: This looks like valid C, that will compile, so no problem here. It's a more open question, not really suited for stackoverflow. However, I think you can set the default max Limit to `INT_MAX`, included in `<limits.h>`, and drop the use of an additional bool value

Comment: @TripeHound the amount is fixed at compile time. Deviations for the other cases might be interesting too.

Comment: If there's more than one object, the user will need to indicate to each function _which_ object they want to operate on. For a fixed number (or a compile-time fixed maximum number), this could just be an "object number" (0...max-1) which indexes either into multiple arrays, or an array of structures. Object numbers could just be "known", or you could track how many are in use and provide a `getNextObject()` function. The arrays/structure would be `static` data to the module so could not be accessed directly by the rest of the code.

Comment: For a variable number (where you don't want to impose a compile-time maximum), it may make more sense to pass a pointer to a structure holding the relevant data to each function. These structures would probably dynamically allocated by some kind of `createObject()` call. This would be moving more to an object-oriented approach.

Comment: @TripeHound Well you are way to advanced in the implementation for my question. It was more about designing the module. Whether it is good practice to design it like this with the internal variables and whether or not I should explicitly pass them to the functions.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with internal variables (they may not be the best for some situations), but at the moment, you only have one instance of `maxExt` and `MaxIsSet` These would need to be stored _per object_ in -- presumably -- the same sort of way each object must be recording its current extension. I would say all those settings would best be held together: either three static internal arrays, one static internal array of structures, or, possibly, using dynamic allocated structures. At the moment, you've got maxExt/MaxIsSet divorced from the extension, and that feels wrong.

Comment: Why is this tagged C89? Home-brewed bool type?

Comment: @Lundin yes the bool is home-brew, because unluckily I am stuck with this standard version in this project. And if it should influence the answer I want to make sure that it is correctly tagged to begin with. Any opinions on the design?

Comment: This seems to be mostly pseudo code, so nobody can have much of an opinion. You have no parameters and it isn't clear where the actual data is stored, beyond those few static variables. On single core embedded systems it is perfectly fine to have static file scope variables for private encapsulation. But perhaps not if you need to return data to the caller. The purpose of the code is quite unclear...

Comment: @Lundin The purpose was demonstrate a "design" and to get feedback whether this design is flawed. The code itself is just an example and servede no purpose other than to demonstrate on how and where to declare the data. Thank you for the feedback, I still seem to struggle to get my point across clearly.

Comment: If you wish to demonstrate a design, you'd be better off by writing the h file as you intend it to be used, complete with typedefs and function prototypes. The single-most important design decision here is: who allocates data and where is it stored.